# Thread deadlock in SpringBoot Infinispan application

Tags: spring-boot, infinispan

We have a Spring-Boot REST application running with Infinispan 13.0.12 caches and we see periodic seemingly random cases where the application becomes un-responsive. A thread dump indicates over 200 threads in this state:

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-379" #11999 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f28900f9800 nid=0x2c68 
   waiting on condition [0x00007f28485c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c09af3e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2163)
    at org.jgroups.util.Credit.decrementIfEnoughCredits(Credit.java:65)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UFC.handleDownMessage(UFC.java:119)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:323)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.down(FlowControl.java:317)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.down(FRAG3.java:139)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.down(ProtocolStack.java:927)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.down(JChannel.java:645)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.send(JChannel.java:484)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.send(JGroupsTransport.java:1161)
```

Our Java configuration looks like this:

```
@Autowired
@Bean
public SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean springEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean(GlobalConfigurationBuilder gcb, ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder) {
    SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean springEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean = new SpringEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    springEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean.addCustomGlobalConfiguration(gcb);
    springEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean.addCustomCacheConfiguration(configurationBuilder);
    return springEmbeddedCacheManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Autowired
@Bean
public EmbeddedCacheManager defaultCacheManager(SpringEmbeddedCacheManager springEmbeddedCacheManager) throws Exception {
    return springEmbeddedCacheManager.getNativeCacheManager();
}

@Bean
public GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigurationBuilder() {
    GlobalConfigurationBuilder result = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
    
    result.transport().addProperty("configurationFile", jgroupsConfigFile);
    
    result.cacheManagerName(IDENTITY_CACHE);
    result.defaultCacheName(IDENTITY_CACHE + "-default");

    result.serialization()
            .marshaller(new JavaSerializationMarshaller())
            .allowList()
            .addClasses(
                    LinkedMultiValueMap.class, 
                    String.class
                );
    
    result.globalState().enable().persistentLocation(DATA_DIR);
                
    return result;      
}

@Bean
public ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder() {
    ConfigurationBuilder result = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        result.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC);
        return result;
}

@Bean
public org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration cacheConfiguration() {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    return builder
            .clustering()
                .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC)
                .remoteTimeout(replicationTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .stateTransfer().timeout(stateTransferTimeoutMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            
            .persistence()
                .addSoftIndexFileStore()
                .shared(false)
                .fetchPersistentState(true)

            .expiration().lifespan(expirationHours, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            
            .build();
}

@Autowired
@Bean
public Cache<String, MultiValueMap<String, String>> identityCache(EmbeddedCacheManager manager, org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration cacheConfiguration) throws IOException {
    Cache<String, MultiValueMap<String, String>> result = manager
            .administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE)
            .getOrCreateCache(IDENTITY_CACHE, cacheConfiguration);
    result.getAdvancedCache().getStats().setStatisticsEnabled(true);
    return result;
}
```

and we run a three node cluster with the default-jgroups-udp.xml config. Can anyone suggest a likely cause? Perhaps the config is sub-optimal?

TIA

```
 <config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroups 
 http://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups-4.0.xsd">
 <UDP mcast_addr="${jgroups.udp.mcast_addr:228.6.7.9}"
    mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:46655}"
    ucast_send_buf_size="1m"
    mcast_send_buf_size="1m"
    ucast_recv_buf_size="20m"
    mcast_recv_buf_size="25m"
    ip_ttl="${jgroups.ip_ttl:2}"
    thread_naming_pattern="pl"
    enable_diagnostics="false"
    bundler_type="no-bundler"
    max_bundle_size="8500"

    thread_pool.min_threads="${jgroups.thread_pool.min_threads:0}"
    thread_pool.max_threads="${jgroups.thread_pool.max_threads:200}"
    thread_pool.keep_alive_time="60000"
 />
 <PING />
 <MERGE3 min_interval="10000" 
       max_interval="30000" 
 />
 <FD_SOCK />
 <FD_ALL timeout="60000" 
       interval="15000" 
       timeout_check_interval="5000" 
 />
 <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="5000" 
 />
 <pbcast.NAKACK2 xmit_interval="100"
               xmit_table_num_rows="50"
               xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
               xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
               resend_last_seqno="true"
 />
 <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="100"
         xmit_table_num_rows="50"
         xmit_table_msgs_per_row="1024"
         xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
         conn_expiry_timeout="0"
 />
 <pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="500"
              desired_avg_gossip="5000"
              max_bytes="1M"
 />
 <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="false"
           install_view_locally_first="true"
           join_timeout="${jgroups.join_timeout:5000}"
 />
 <UFC max_credits="2m" 
    min_threshold="0.40"
 />
 <MFC max_credits="2m" 
    min_threshold="0.40"
 />
 <FRAG3 frag_size="8000"/>
 </config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a replicated cache. This means that reads are always local, so the stack trace must be on a write (or rebalance).

The block means that the sender is waiting for credits from a receiver, which don't arrive, so the receiver must be stuck in sth. Also, the stack trace is not complete; can you show the entire trace?

To know what's going on, it would be good to see thread dumps of *all* members. I suggest zip them up and post a link to the zip here...
Cheers

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtj4m965vc8j7n3/dump.zip?dl=0

hope that works

Comment: I'll need to wait for the next incident to get thread dumps from all members.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zq8reia8f379bs7/dumps.zip?dl=0

this is one un-responsive node and the other two

Comment: OK, so nodes 2 and 3 are normal. Node 1 blocks on missing credits (from 2 or 3). This is strange, as node 2 or 3 don't have any thread blocked in the application... I assume you only have a 3-node cluster? Can you post your jgroupsConfiguration (XML) file? One possible cause could be that the 200 blocked threads max out the thread pool and therefore incoming credit responses are dropped. However, that brings back the question why the sender threads are blocked! You could try to increase the max thread pool size...

Comment: have added xml to original post - yes only three nodes

Comment: I suggest change `thread_pool.max_threads` to `500` and `UFC.max_credits` to `8M`. This is a band aid though, as we still don't know whay node1 blocks...

Comment: thanks - will try that. I expect we'll get some more "random" events and maybe we'll get better clues from the traces next time.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhf48ky3e25kxxa/dumps.20221126.zip?dl=0

Another incident - not been able to update anything yet. Node3 was the offender.

Comment: Offender? I don't see any node blocking in the nodeX.txt files...

Comment: The application stopped responding to http requests.

Unfortunately these things occur out of hours so we are reliant on support staff to report and take dumps etc. Service needs to be restored as a priority, so perhaps diagnosis is not always optimal.

We are looking to make the jgroups changes this week and will report back.

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: We have now updated and deployed the jgroups xml file as recommended

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/069qlo9xgexc1vv/dumps.20221212.zip?dl=0

It was all going so well! Node 1 this time was "busy" and unresponsive to http.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JGroups. It seems that Infinispan is blocked on state transfer... Weird that spring locks a ConcurrentHashMap multiple times: `- locked <0x00000006c02ae5c0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)`

Comment: Thanks @Bela Ban.  Is there any Infinispan support on this thread?

Comment: Hey @AdrianSmith it's best if you come over on the https://infinispan.zulipchat.com chat to make this a bit more interactive

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14260 ?

Are you using ACL cache authorisations?

Our temporary fix was to disable cache authorisations which solves all our locking issues. Waiting on the patch for 13 and 14 to be finalised